# Web Design Practices to best handle various devices

Tags: html, css, web

I'm considered above novice in web design and I've found holes in my education. My professor taught us with Dreamweaver and simply used it because Dreamweaver does 80% of the work (this was through a Business School, efficiency was the focus not quality). 
 This didn't teach me hardly anything even though I scored high in the class. I'm doing more web design and currently I'm having trouble understanding how to program to account for various devices. What I want to know are code examples, articles (I've found a few and they didn't have anything helpful), or anything else that could be conducive to filling my holes.
 I want to program code professionally that handles screen widths, browsers, and other device quirks that can affect a web page. Basically I'm lacking in good practices in formatting. Thank you for your patience and time!

Comment: You don't. You code a responsive design, with breakpoints in CSS to cater for different sizes in screens. And you don't use `px` for sizes anywhere, except for distinct image-sizes (and maybe a couple other very specific items). You use `em` or `%` for size, and you set breakpoints for when the screen gets too narrow for whatever element. You do not care about type of browser, because you check in all major ones at least and make sure it works in all of them. You don't use crap like Dreamweaver, and you make sure you follow standards and use semantic HTML.

Comment: In the modern web exist media-queries in CSS for defining different styles for different screen sizes. This is already made easy by a lot of modern frameworks like Bootstrap or Foundation. Also interesting would be SASS, if you want to do things professionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some good advice here although a couple of things mentioned may cause you some confusion given you will be researching responsive design for the first time. First off it is ok to use **px** sizes and you do not always have to use **%** or **em's**. Your choice of measurements depends on your design and how you would like it to respond. SASS is definitely something worth learning but for now it has no relevance to you learning responsive design.

There are endless tutorials on youtube ([try this channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3IdEqpjMvQ)) about building basic responsive websites. If you want to learn responsive web design and really understand the principals behind it then I would recommend this book [Responsive Web Design](https://abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design). Its a very short read but is a great resource.

Also you mentioned that you have limited coding skills so I am assuming you only have basic HTML. Although HTML in principal is easy to understand, when it comes to building responsive websites you really need to add extra focus not simply on semantic tags, but on how your HTML is layed out. Again this depends on your design and how you want your site to look on different screen sizes, and as you start to build your first projects it will become clearer why I have mentioned the importance of your HTML layout.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into those links. I do have understanding of html semantic tags and using css to account for some device quirks but not much. It has mostly been guess work on my account because like I said my teacher sucked at teaching. I tried asking to have some things taught at the code level and she blew it off talking about how business wants quanity and then later you can do quality. Of course we never got to the quality part.... much disappointment. Anyway thank you again!

Comment: The class was basic web design taught through Monfort Business School at UNC in Greeley, CO.

Comment: I was thinking your web design may have been a module in more comprehensive computer science course. This might excuse your professor for only dabbling in HTML. The fact that the course was WEB DESIGN, yeh that's a bad teacher alright. Dreamweaver is good for quick development which is what companies want, but it teaches you nothing. I'm aware that college courses can be pricey so if you're willing to put in the time there are tons of online resources like [TreeHouse](https://teamtreehouse.com) and [Lynda](https://www.lynda.com/) that are just as good as any course you'll pay huge amounts for.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to account for multiple devices and their specific widths, you are probably looking for [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), a type of tag used within CSS.

Media queries create break point at specified widths, applying certain css only when the screen goes above/below the specified width. This will allow you to create a different viewing experience for multiple devices.

However media queries will not be able to handle dynamically changing sizes (think resizing your browser). For this you will want to do some research into Responsive web design.